# Undefined behavior of std::future as return type?

Tags: c++, c++11, asynchronous, pthreads, future

In my case, I use std::future as a return type but get a undefined behavior.
The code is below:

```
#include <future>
#include <iostream>
#include <pthread.h>

std::future<bool> update() {
  int c = 1; 
  //std::cout << "?" << c << std::endl; // debug line
  auto lambda = [&] () -> bool {
    int b = 0; 
    for(int i = 0; i < 10000000; ++i) {
      b += 1; 
    }  
    std::cout << "?" << c << std::endl;
    return c == 1; 
  }; 
  return std::async(std::launch::async, lambda);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  auto f2 = update();
  std::cout << f2.get() << std::endl;
  return 0; 
}
```

I compiled this piece of code by `g++-4.7.2 -std=c++11 test_future.cc -lpthread` and get the following output result:

```
?0
0
```

But when I uncommented the `debug line` above, the output became `1`(as expected). Besides, if I use `std::future` as a parameter with `update` function in stead of return value, I can also get the right output result.

I want to know what's the problem here. The bug of g++ or the bug of the usage? Thanks.

Comment: Return... to the future? You'll need plutonium or 1.21 gigawats of electricity and then exceed speeds of precisely 88 miles per hour which activates the flux capacitor.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you capture the variable `c` by reference, combined with you running the lambda asynchronously. The last part means that the `update` function may have returned before the lambda actually runs, and it now has a reference to a variable that no longer exists.

The reason it *seems* to work if you have the debug line, is because of just *undefined behavior*.

So the problem doesn't have anything to do with you returning the `std::future`.

The obvious solution is of course to capture `c` by value instead, and if it's not possible in your actual code then you might have to rethink your design.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your lambda `auto lambda = [&] () -> bool` is capturing by reference.  The reference to c could be dangling, since the thread could execute after the function exits.

You should probably capture by value `auto lambda = [=] () -> bool` instead.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like undefined behavior to me. You capture `c` by reference, but it will have fallen out of scope by the time `lambda` executes.

Therefore `c == 1` is undefined behavior, because `c` has fallen out of scope. If you capture *by value* you should be fine.

```
auto lambda = [c] () -> bool {
  int b = 0; 
  for(int i = 0; i < 10000000; ++i) {
    b += 1; 
  }  
  std::cout << "?" << c << std::endl;
  return c == 1; 
};
```

Comment: If you want to modify a capture by value variable, then you need to make the lambda mutable. `[c] () mutable -> bool`